# How to put JSON object into a python dataframe

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I have a json object that looks like this:

```
{
  "Category_One": [
    [
      "CAT_1_VALUE_LINE_ONE
    ],
    [
      "CAT_1_VALUE_LINE_TWO
    ],
],

  "Category_Two": [
    [
      "CAT_2_VALUE_LINE_ONE
    ],
    [
      "CAT_2_VALUE_LINE_TWO
    ],
],
  "Category_Three": [
    [
      "CAT_3_VALUE_LINE_ONE
    ],
    [
      "CAT_3_VALUE_LINE_TWO
    ],
]
}
```

I need to convert or transform it to something that looks like this (I believe this is known as a NESTED JSON Object?

```
{
   "Category_One": "CAT_1_VALUE_LINE_ONE",
   "Category_Two": "CAT_2_VALUE_LINE_ONE",
   "Category_Three": "CAT_3_VALUE_LINE_ONE"
},
{
   "Category_One": "CAT_1_VALUE_LINE_TWO",
   "Category_Two": "CAT_2_VALUE_LINE_TWO",
   "Category_Three": "CAT_3_VALUE_LINE_TWO"
},
```

and then I think once I get it in this format, I can put into a dataframe..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First of all, your existing code has syntax errors**. Then I can suggest one way to make it a **list of dictionaries** from existing `dictionary` and finally make a **data frame** like below-

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
       'Category_One': [['CAT_1_VALUE_LINE_ONE'],
        ['CAT_1_VALUE_LINE_TWO']],
       'Category_Two': [['CAT_2_VALUE_LINE_ONE'],
        ['CAT_2_VALUE_LINE_TWO']],
       'Category_Three': [['CAT_3_VALUE_LINE_ONE'],
        ['CAT_3_VALUE_LINE_TWO']]
      }

final_result = []
for i in range(len(data['Category_One'])):
    result = {}
    for key, value in data.items():
        result[key] = value[i][0]
    final_result.append(result)
df = pd.DataFrame(final_result)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
           Category_One          Category_Two        Category_Three
0  CAT_1_VALUE_LINE_ONE  CAT_2_VALUE_LINE_ONE  CAT_3_VALUE_LINE_ONE
1  CAT_1_VALUE_LINE_TWO  CAT_2_VALUE_LINE_TWO  CAT_3_VALUE_LINE_TWO
```

**Working Code:** https://replit.com/@SanyAhmed/listofdicttodf?v=1#main.py

Comment: I think we are nearly there - but this only shows the 1st character of value - i.e. it prints C, C, C, C, C - because the 1st character is 'C'

Comment: Then just update this line: `result[key] = value[i][0]` to `result[key] = value[i]`,(without the zero) I just used your existing data.

Comment: you just have to remove the [0] and its ok.. but how do we get panda to print the full df? it just gives me a summary??

Comment: see here: https://replit.com/@SanyAhmed/listofdicttodf?v=1#main.py, I guess you need to tweak the pandas dataframe settings to view all the dataframe